# How to change backgrounds on mouseenter with array of colors

Tags: javascript, mouseenter

Having a hard time figuring out how to change the background color of 3 paragraphs to the colors in an array on `mouseenter` using JavaScript. Any tips? This is my array:

```
function changeColors() {
  var colors = ['pink', 'turquoise', 'green'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your html is like so:

```html
<p class="my-paragraphs">Paragraph 1</p>
<p class="my-paragraphs">Paragraph 2</p>
<p class="my-paragraphs">Paragraph 3</p>
```

Your js will create an array that targets these, and then adds a style dynamically:

```js
function changeColors() {
  var colors = ['pink', 'turquoise', 'green'];
  var myParagraphs = document.querySelectorAll('.my-paragraphs');

  myParagraphs.forEach( function(paragraph, index){
    paragraph.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
      paragraph.style = `background-color: ${colors[index]}`
    })
    paragraph.addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
      paragraph.style = ``
    })
  })
}

changeColors()
```

[Here is a codepen](https://codepen.io/slutske22/pen/BayvYWM?editors=1011)

There's a million ways to do this, but I recommend that instead of having an array in javascript with color names, you create css classes that contain a `background-color: anyColorYouLikeByPinkFloyd` key value pair, and then use javascript to add and remove the classes from your paragraphs.  Programmatically changing the `style` attribute in JS should be used with caution.

[Here is a codepen that achieves the same effect with css classes](https://codepen.io/slutske22/pen/xxbmYXL?editors=1111).  A little more verbose, but safer.  Programatically rewriting `style=""` like I did in the previous codepen will delete any other styles that may be attached to your element.